# How, where and when to refresh the token in the Angular 2/5 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application, angular5

Currently I'm working with -

- Django REST Framework
- Angular 5
- RxJS +
- OAuth2

The list of paths of all components except the LoginComponent I have AuthGuard where I check whether the data on the token and the user in the localstorage of the browser.

If data is available I will return True. But as soon as the token expires, I can't do anything with the user.

If I get a 401 code in the service, I can't even redirect the user to the login page since I can't use the router in service.

Basically I am wondering how, when and where to update the token in my web app?

Kindly give some knowledge on how to work with tokens. Also it would be helpful if any code example is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is too broad, and opinion-based. But if you want a thrid party point of view, here are my two cents :

## Storing the Token

Depending on your application, you have several ways of storing a Token.

#### LocalStorage

The first solution, the one you used, is storing it in the local storage. This way, the Token will remain on the device as long as you (or the user) doesn't delete it.

#### Session storage

The session storage will behave same as local storage, except that the token will be deleted once the user closes his session.

#### Service storage

Last option : storing it in a service : your token will remain as long as your user stays in the scope of Angular (meaning, doesn't reload or change tab).

#### How to chose ?

Depends on your application. If you make an application involving high risks after login, then you should consider using the session storage, so that the user gets "removed" as soon as he leaves the page. For a casual application, stay on the local storage. And if you REALLY want to lock your application up, use the service storage.

## When to store the Token

Seems obvious, but you should store it when the user logs in.

## Update the Token

You should not have to do that. The Token matches an user, or an user session. The only update you should do is a deletion, not a rewrite.

## Where to update the Token

In a service dedicated to Token management. This is the best practice.

## More information

You said you had an Auth Guard. This is a good practice. but **yes, you can redirect the user from your service**. Why wouldn't you ? That's the usual way of asking an user to connect ! Use the router in your service, really, there's no issue with that.

From my point of view, and what you described, except for the routing in a guard, you're doing it pretty well. The only advice I would give you is to handle an expiration date on your token, if your application is high risk profiled (and you have to use the session storage).

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, it is very wage for me. You wrote that you don't see a problem in calling the router in service, but I have an error when I call:

      .catch(function(error: Response | any) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return Observable.of(false);
      });

Error message: TypeError: cannot read property 'navigation' undefined

Router what I call the standard way. Props in its constructor:

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router) {}

Comment: Your error comes from `navigation`. You must call navigation somewhere, and it's not a function (it's router.navigate). If you can post your code, I could help you !

Comment: I made a sketch of the app is not completely finished. Service put real. How to change the refreshToken method?

Comment: Whaaaaat ? You don't refresh a Token like that ! If you want to refresh a Token you log your user out and force him to create a new Token !

Comment: I want to update the token on the fly so that the user does not have to enter each time login and the password.

Comment: In my understanding, the token is the key for working with data systems without providing information about the user. Security is achieved by lifetime of the token. And the lifetime of the token below, the more often we need to refresh and the safer for the user.

Comment: Yes and no. A Token is a string made of information about the user. The security is achieved by the Token validity (encrypted string) and its lifetime. If this Token matches what you decided in your backend, then your user is authorized. Given those informations, you don't have to refresh it on the fly like you do ; you have to refresh it **when its expiration date is over**. And furthermore, you don't refresh it, **your user does**. What's the point of refreshing your Token at every click ? The expiration date becomes useless in this case.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://jwt.io/) and you will understand how it works.

Comment: How can I change the application? Just to kick a user if the token is expired? But what if the user is active and performs actions in the application, then it will throw unexpectedly. On many sites the user does not eject if it is active. May be you have links to sources where I can read, I would be happy.

Comment: Yes, if the Token is expired, you kick the user ! If you don't, then why would you have an expiration date ? it will never be of any use ! If you're scared it will disconnect him, you can hold the Token in the session storage too, so that when he closes his browser, next time he comes, he will have to log in. I give you the JWT website, but you can find many more just a google search of `JSON web token`

Comment: I figured it out, the problem was that the context was lost.

Comment: .catch(this.handleError) --> replace -->.catch(err => this.handleError(err))